# Segmentation Error: Local Machine Fails (16gb) but AWS EC2 works (1gb)

Tags: pandas, segmentation-fault, zsh

I understand  this is a little vague but not sure where else to go to or things to debug. My python script was running fine yesterday. I made minor changes today and now it only runs successfully on my Amazon LightSail (ec2) machine. Everything I read about segmentation errors is that there is not enough memory, however my local machine has 16gb of ram while the cloud machine only has 1gb. Plus I am not working with big files? The files being imported/manipulated are typically under 2mb and there are like 7-10 files.

I feel it may be something related to my terminal/zsh rather than my codes.

The below is the error code I can not seem to manage to get around.
I've done enough research to find the python faulthandler module `import faulthandler; faulthandler.enable()`  to give the debugging below:

```
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x000000010c58edc0 (most recent call first):
  File "/Users/garrett/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1795 in <genexpr>
  File "/Users/garrett/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1797 in <listcomp>
  File "/Users/garrett/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 1797 in count
  File "GmailDownloader.py", line 215 in <module>
zsh: segmentation fault  python *.py
```

The code seems to regularly break on line 215 while trying to compute a gorupby in pandas but it is very similar to other groupbys in the code that were successful before it.

I am on a Mac Catlina using the pre-baked zsh for my terminal handling but even when I switch to good ol' bash using `chsh -s /bin/bash` in my terminal and then running the code I still get a zsh segmentation error.

I have recently tried out PyCharm today and it asked for permissions to store something in a bin folder to which I just said yes. I'm not sure if that is correlated at all or not.

The full code repository: https://github.com/GarrettMarkScott/AutomotiveCRMPuller

Ongoing list of other things I have tried:

- Trashing the Terminal preferences (~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist)

Answer (score 0):

I almost threw in the towel but tried to reinstall my pandas since it was mentioned in my bug error and what do you know it worked after running `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Would of been impossible without the FaultHandler! Hopefully this helps someone out there!